# Is there a way to check if a website places cookies based on there URL?

Tags: php, cookies, affiliate

Is there a way to check if a website places cookies based on their URL? I would prefer to do this in PHP. Wonder if I would need to use CURL?

Just trying to figure out how to ping a url to see if it would place a cookie on my machine and then get a little info about that cookie. The reason I am doing this is because I am trying to find an easy way to catch typo squatters for my brand so I want to see if affiliate pixels are being placed for my affiliate programs.

Comment: "Affiliate pixels" != cookies. Do you mean third party cookies? Then that's not trivial.

Answer (score 1):

To get the headers received by sending a get request to an url, use:

```
$headers = get_headers('http://example.com');
```

After, just look for the cookie in the headers. The get_headers spec is here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php